# How to create a moving texture effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I would like to create something like the red electric board in the [video](https://youtu.be/mA_9M9XDm8I) using blender, but I don't know how to do it.

I would like to know if there are any experts who can help me.

Thank you in advance.

---

The English text was generated from the Japanese text below.

[動画](https://youtu.be/mA_9M9XDm8I)にある赤い電光掲示板のようなものをblenderで作成したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

有識者の方がいましたらご教授いただきたいです。

よろしくお願い致します。

---

Mr A, thank you for your [prompt response](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/305717/35559)!
But I am sorry, there is one more problem.
I'm using blender 4.0 and I can't find the "Add" part.
I went to the shading tab, "Add" and checked everything, but there was no "Add".
If you could please tell me how to add this "Add".

Mr A様、早急に対応していただきありがとうございます！
ですが申し訳ございません、もう一つ問題点がございまして
今blender4.0というバージョンを使っているのですが「Add」の部分が見つかりません。
シェーディングタブから「追加」して、すべて確認をしてみたのですが「Add」はありませんでした。
もしよろしければ、この「Add」を追加する方法のご教授をお願いいたします。

Comment: The node labelled "Add" is a "vector math" node.  Its name changes depending on which mode you set it to.

Comment: You're welcome! As @Nathan said, it is the *Vector Math* node. If you have a question on one of the answers, please post it as a comment on that answer. This will notify the person who contributed that answer.

Answer (score 1):

This effect is typically done through shaders by displacing the UVs of the plane with time (frame number/frame rate). You can achieve this using a shader node setup like the following.

[image: Shader]

Please note that the purple field is one controlled with a driver. You add a driver by typing `#frame/24/2`. `frame` is the current frame number. I divide it by 24, because that's the current frame rate of the file. I divide it by 2 afterwards, because the texture was sliding too fast. Feel free to adjust the driver to get the look you want.